# C++ equivalent of algebraic datatype?

Tags: c++, haskell, algebraic-data-types

Let's say I have this Haskell code:

```hs
data RigidBody = RigidBody Vector3 Vector3 Float Shape -- position, velocity, mass and shape
data Shape = Ball Float -- radius
           | ConvexPolygon [Triangle]
```

What would be the best way to express this in C++?

```
struct Rigid_body {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 velocity;
    float mass;
    *???* shape;
};
```

The thing I'm asking is how to represent shape inside the struct when it can be one of two types.

Comment: What is the question? How to reference a different type `Shape` not yet defined? How to create a type `Shape` that is really one of a set of other types? All of the above? You might want to consider looking into a different programing paradigm, translating haskell directly into C++ is most probably not going to work that well...

Comment: I would think the easiest way would be a union of structs, but I'd rather try to write a parser for Haskell than program anything in C++.

Comment: The thing I'm asking is how to translate this kind of "variant" type into whatever paradigm C++ uses. See my edit.

Comment: @user3133295: With respect, it would be better to learn C++ first and then tackle this problem, rather than trying to translate Haskell into C++ without prior knowledge of C++ idioms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are different approaches that can be used to solve that problem in C++.

The pure-OO approach you would define an interface `Shape` and have the two different options as derived types implementing that interface. Then the `RigidBody` would contain a pointer to a `Shape` that would be set to refer to either a `Ball` or a `ConvexPolygon`. Pro: people love OO (not sure this is a pro really :)), it is easily extensible (you can add more shapes later on without changing the type). Con: You should define a proper interface for `Shape`, it requires dynamic allocation of memory.

Putting OO aside, you can use a `boost::variant` or similar type, that is basically a tagged union that will hold one of the types. Pro: no dynamic allocations, shape is local to the object. Con: not pure-OO (people love OO, you remember right?), not so easy to extend, cannot use the shape *generically*

Comment: I don't really care about using it generically. I don't want to force the creator of my `Rigid_body` to manually allocate memory. I'd rather make two constructors for the rigid body then that constructs the shapes themselves.

Comment: @user3133295: Constructors in C++ are not *constructors* in Haskell. Memory allocations is something you will need to do eventually if you are doing C++, and this is not a horrible burden on the user (the constructor of your `RigidBody` could take a `Shape*`. Really the OO approach is far more common in C++ than the `boost::variant` approach. If you use dynamically allocated memory remember to use smart pointers to release the burden or manual memory management.

Comment: What if I don't want the two shapes to have anything at all in common? I can't `dynamic_cast` a `Shape` to a `Ball` because apparently `Shape` is not a polymorphic type.

Comment: @user3133295: If you want to use polymorphism you need to make your types polymorphic. If nothing else to be able to `delete` the object at one point!

Comment: I do not see how 1) OO even matters the slightest since C++ is multi-paradigm and 2) how `boost::variant` is not object-oriented (inb4 irrelevant inheritance shit).

Comment: Boost variant is not performant since it doubly allocates all memory, including at least one on heap, even if variant is on stack

Answer (score 13):

To throw another possibility in here, you can also use `boost::variant` which is being added to the standard library in C++17 as `std::variant`:

```
struct Ball { float radius; };
struct ConvexPolygon { Triangle t; }

using Shape = boost::variant<Ball, ConvexPolygon>;
```

The advantages of this approach:

- Type-safe, unlike tagged unions
- Can hold complex types, unlike unions
- Does not require a uniform interface across all "child" types, unlike OO

Some disadvantages:

- Sometimes requires you to do a type check when accessing the variable to confirm that it is the type you want it to be, unlike OO
- Requires you to use boost, or be C++17 compatible; these may be difficult with some compilers or some organizations where OO and unions are universally supported

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to do this in C++ is the inheritance-based solution given in Justin Wood's answer.  Canonically, you endow the `Shape` with virtual functions that each kind of `Shape`

However, C++ also has `union` types.  You can do "tagged unions" instead:

```
struct Ball { /* ... */ };
struct Square { /* ... */ };
struct Shape {
  int tag;
  union {
    Ball b;
    Square s;
    /* ... */
  }
};
```

You use the `tag` member to say whether the `Shape` is a `Ball` or a `Square` or whatever else.  You can `switch` on the `tag` member and whatnot.

This has the disadvantage that a `Shape` is one `int` larger than the biggest of `Ball` and `Square` and the others; objects in OCaml and whatnot do not have this problem.

Which technique you use will depend on how you're using the `Shape`s.

Comment: Union types are limited in C++03, and awkward to use in C++11. If any of the elements in the union is not a POD type you will need to add your own constructor, copy constructor, assignment and manually manage the lifetime of the objects. That is what `boost::variant` solves for you.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes.  I can't imagine why a `Ball` or `Square` wouldn't be POD, though.

Comment: Well, in the Haskell code it is not `Square`, but `ConvexPolygon`, which might have a variable number of vertices

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Point taken.

Comment: Horror!  This approach surely will lead nowhere but madness.  You are re-inventing polymorphism through a union and integer tag and then trusting that the other developers will follow the rules for accessing elements.  Using an OO hierarchy and, if specialized methods are required and can't be generalized through virtual functions, using a dynamic_cast to the specialized type will provide you with type safety not afforded by the union design here.

Comment: @Nathan: Yes, you can use a pile of `dynamic_cast`s instead.  I do not know how to `switch` on the dynamic type of an object, however.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to create a base class `Shape`. From here, you can create your actual shape classes, `Ball` and `ConvexPolygon`. You are going to want to make sure that `Ball` and `ConvexPolygon` are children of the base class.

```
class Shape {
    // Whatever commonalities you have between the two shapes, could be none.
};

class Ball: public Shape {
    // Whatever you need in your Ball class
};

class ConvexPolygon: public Shape {
    // Whatever you need in your ConvexPolygon class
};
```

Now, you can make a generalized object like this

```
struct Rigid_body {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 velocity;
    float mass;
    Shape *shape;
};
```

and when you actually initialize your `shape` variable, you can initialize it with either a `Ball` or `ConvexPolygon` class. You can continue making as many shapes as you would like.

Comment: You probably want `Rigid_body` to have a `Shape *` rather than a `Shape` so you can avoid slicing.

Comment: It has since been fixed.